# RPG with Rats as PCs?

Tags: product-identification

I am tryting to remember what the name of that (German?) RPG was where you play a rat in some sort of decrepit house or mall or something. One of the worst enemies would be Cats. (It was definitely rats, and not mice.)

I remember that it used a rather simple mechanic of just d6, some keywords on each character and some... checkboxes I believe.

Rats were of different breeds (tribes?) and one of them were labrats.

Comment: Rats or mice?..

Comment: @enkryptor rattus rattus.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pretty sure the product is [Ratten!](https://www.prometheusgames.de/verlag/verlagsprodukte/pocket-rpgs/ratten/) ("Rats!") by the German publisher Prometheus Games (who until 2017 also used to publish Savage Worlds in Germany).

Translated pitch description:

> Welcome to the world of Rats!, the role-playing game in which players can slip into the fur of a rat and experience all kinds of adventures in the Rat Castle (an abandoned department store).
>
> Although the player characters in this role-playing game are of course strongly humanised - who wants to play real animals? -, they are still rats: they don't walk on two legs, they don't have thumbs and they can't cook very well.
>
> The rats live in clan-like groups - routs - distributed in the departments of the former department store. At the moment there is peace, but this has not always been the case and the danger that old enmities between the gangs will flare up again is always in the air.

It also describes cats as the principal enemies in some other blurbs.

It has been translated into English under the name [Packs!](https://www.prometheusshop.de/engl.-rollenspiele/packs/3837/packs-corebook-hardcover)

Comment: While I must take issue with this game's assumptions on the basis of [*The Muppets Take Manhattan*](https://youtu.be/MtWpX9RwrVU), enjoy your +1 anyway. `:-)`

Comment: @HeyICanChan Heh. Pretty sure the text is referencing the 2007 Ratatouille movie - the first edition of the rules seems to be from the same year.

Comment: Fair enough. But can we agree that there should be both a Muppets RPG *and* a Pixar RPG?